# My Smart-Pad doesn't work, even when I activate it

Tags: laptop, touchpad, smart

I have an Asus X5DIJ, and I have had it since Christmas. However, today, the Smart-Pad stopped working.  I wasn't clicking anything, I was just typing. Someone suggested downloading drivers, and I'm not to good with guides, so can anyone assist me?

Also, when I click on the Smart-Pad icon in the notification area, that icon is crossed out. There is a red `X` over it, no matter if it is on / off.

Can anyone help me, this has happened to my cousin who has the same laptop as me, he now uses a mouse, but I'd rather keep the Smart - Pad.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm bad in english. 
How to install the drivers you can read [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Value-line/G560-touchpad-issue/td-p/345725/page/5). But be careful not all of them suitable for your laptop brand. 
install driver ASUS ELANTECH TOUCHPAD DRIVER **Version:7.0.5.9** (if you want to choose right version of driver for another laptop you can do it [here](http://www.drivershq.com/driver-update/keyboard-mouse-touchpad/elan-digital-systems/elan-ps-2-port-smart-pad/asus-elantech-touchpad-driver/)).

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with my Elan touchpad and my solution after a bunch of head ache was to shut down computer, unplug, and pull the battery out. After doing so I touched the touchpad while computer is off and the power button.  Then put battery back in and started up and it was solved... Magic! It worked for my problem (Touchpad was not even showing up in device manager computer didn't think it had one, it wouldn't even work when I booted into Linux) There must of been some really weird charge on the capacitor so this allowed it to discharge.  Think of it as hitting the reset button.

And of course make sure your touchpad is enabled in the bios or with the touchpad on/off button either on your keyboard F-Keys or a button next to the touchpad (that the touchpad off button is not set).  Also check touchpad settings in your mouse settings section to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to visit Asus support website to get the driver and related information.

check this link   [Disable Touchpad and Touchpad Scroll](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20070413130002265&board_id=3&model=G2P&page=1&SLanguage=en-us)

There are `download menu`, where you can get your laptop driver that should be made for for your laptop.`Get your notepad` drivers [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=X5DIJ&p=3&s=193). . Just Select your operating system for which system software required.